# Key mapping with chained keypresses

Tags: vim

I normally use the `ctrl-a` and `ctrl-e` to go to the start and end of a line in vim. For example:

```
:inoremap <C-a> <Esc>0i
:inoremap <C-e> <Esc>$li
```

However, I would like to make  go to the first word, which would be:

```
:inoremap <C-a><C-l> <Esc>^i
```

However, it does seem to register the second keypress. Is there a way to make sure that chained keypresses are always picked up that way, or how is this normally done?

Comment: This is pretty weird, your command is working without any problems for me

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on vi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: try with vanilla vim within a normal terminal (instead of tmux/screen) or gvim. those mappings should work. And those mappings are not good ideas

Comment: @Kent thanks, why do you say "those mappings are not good ideas"? What might be better?

Comment: @David542 you may want to check `i_ctrl-o`

Comment: @Kent of course, but what would be the difference? It would still be three key presses and get me to the same place. Why would that approach be better?

Comment: @David542 probably you dont use the insert mode c-(x) functions. Sometimes they are handy. if you created those mappings, you cannot use them anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:inoremap <C-a> <Esc>0i
:inoremap <C-e> <Esc>$li
```

could be improved by avoiding the unnecessary mode switching (and weird `$li`):

```
:inoremap <C-a> <Home>
:inoremap <C-e> <End>
```

For jumping to the first printable character of the line, you could do:

```
:inoremap <C-a><C-l> <Home><S-Right>
```

Comment: thank for these suggestions, these are very helpful. Out of curiosity, what is the difference between doing `<Home>` vs. `0` ? Also, what is `<S-Right>` ?

Comment: (I don't have `Home` or `End` on my keyboard)